# How to insert results from another select into new table with extra column value added?

Tags: sql, t-sql, asp.net-membership

In an ASP.NET UsersInRoles Membership table I have a `aspnet_Users` table with `UserId` et cetera, I have a `aspnet_Roles` table with `RoleId` and `RoleName` et cetera, and I have a table that joins them together called `aspnet_UsersInRoles` with `RoleId` and `UserId`.

Now I want to give all users that do not have the `RoleName` "MyRoleName" the existing `RoleName` "RoleNameToBeGiven".

I can get all the `UserId`s without the property "MyRoleName" as follows:

```
SELECT u.UserId FROM dbo.aspnet_Users u
INNER JOIN dbo.aspnet_UsersInRoles r
ON u.UserId = r.UserId
WHERE r.RoleId NOT IN (SELECT RoleID FROM dbo.aspnet_Roles WHERE RoleName 
    = 'MyRoleName')
```

Now I want to add every `UserId` obtained in this query into `aspnet_UsersInRoles` with the `RoleId` belonging to RoleName "RoleNameToBeGiven". To obtain the `RoleId` of "RoleNameToBeGiven" I have the following query:

```
SELECT RoleId FROM dbo.aspnet_Roles
WHERE RoleName = 'RoleNameToBeGiven'
```

The question is: how do I combine this two queries and insert *every* `UserId` obtained in the first query into the `aspnet_UsersInRoles" table with the`RoleId` obtained in the second query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I found a working solution with the help of [a cursor](http://stevestedman.com/2013/04/t-sql-a-simple-example-using-a-cursor/):

```
DECLARE @UserId AS uniqueidentifier;
DECLARE @RoleId AS uniqueidentifier;
DECLARE @UserCursor as CURSOR;   

SET @UserCursor = CURSOR FOR
SELECT u.UserId 
    FROM dbo.aspnet_Users u
    INNER JOIN dbo.aspnet_UsersInRoles r
    ON u.UserId = r.UserId
    WHERE r.RoleId NOT IN 
        (SELECT RoleID 
            FROM dbo.aspnet_Roles 
            WHERE RoleName = 'MyRoleName')

SET @RoleId = (
    SELECT RoleId 
    FROM dbo.aspnet_Roles
    WHERE RoleName = 'RoleNameToBeGiven'
    )

OPEN @UserCursor; 
FETCH NEXT FROM @UserCursor INTO @UserId
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN 
    PRINT cast(@UserId as VARCHAR (50)) + ' ' + cast(@RoleId as VARCHAR (50));
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT UserId, RoleId FROM dbo.aspnet_UsersInRoles 
               WHERE UserId = @UserId AND RoleId = @RoleId)
    INSERT INTO dbo.aspnet_UsersInRoles (UserId,RoleId)
    VALUES(@UserId,@RoleId);
    FETCH NEXT FROM @UserCursor INTO @UserId
END  

CLOSE @UserCursor; 
DEALLOCATE @UserCursor;
```